# Can Achocha survive from being connected by only 1 root?

Tags: cucumbers

I almost pulled off all of my Achocha roots when pulling it out of the pack. how can I try to make it bounce back to being a viable plant for planting, or is it gone?

Answer (score 1):

From what I discovered from almost snapping the plant was putting the plant mobilized in a bucket, and letting it grow. it got mobilized in about 24 hours, and almost doubled in size in about 24 hours, so like a broken bone immobilize the plant, and give it water, then it will quickly heal.